# Can't get .env variables to update Nodejs express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, dotenv

I cannot get my .env file to update which only contains the following variable:

```
DB_URI=mongodb+srv://user:pw@cluster1.jz57tt3.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I am attempting to switch to a new mongodb cluster by updating the DB_URI variable. However, it is still connecting to the old one. The old variable must be cached somewhere.

Relevant code:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

const moment = require('moment');
app.locals.moment = moment;

// middleware
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// database connection
const dbURI = process.env.DB_URI;
mongoose
  .connect(dbURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then((result) => app.listen(80))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I have tried:

```
pm2 kill
```

```
pm2 restart all --update-env
```

```
npm cache clean --force
```

I have also tried: deleting the .env file and creating a new one, uninstalling dotenv and reinstalling, uninstalling pm2 and reinstalling, uninstalling and reinstalling all npm packages.

None of these seemed to update the variable and I am still being connected to a different mongodb cluster.

Answer (score -1):

I had my env file named `config.env` not `.env`.

After changing it works.